# XSLT; XML transformation with nested attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to change the value of MODOUT in the below code from 4 to 6 for certain MODIDs, but leave those with other values of MODOUT unchanged.
I would like to do this for different values of OWNINST.
So, for example, for OWNINST 1439582|1 I would like to change MODOUT to 4 for MODIDs 09|24864, 09|24899 but not 09|24865, and for OWNINST 1439582|1 I would like to change MODOUT to 4 for MODID 09|12345 but not 09|24863.  I do not want to change any modules for OWNINST 1439582|2 (highlighting the fact a Student can have more than one instance)
I am familiar with how to change a field at the Instance level using one identifier (e.g. changing FUNDCOMP using OWNINST), but not how to change a field with two identifiers, namely OWNINST and MODID.  Please can someone advise?

```
<Student>
    <BIRTHDTE>1986-05-29</BIRTHDTE>
    <ULN>8402398897</ULN>
    <Instance>
        <NUMHUS>1</NUMHUS>
        <OWNINST>1439582|1</OWNINST>
        <FUNDCOMP>2</FUNDCOMP>
        <StudentOnModule>
            <MODID>09|24864</MODID>
            <MODOUT>4</MODOUT>
            <MODSTAT>2</MODSTAT>
        </StudentOnModule>
        <StudentOnModule>
            <MODID>09|24865</MODID>
            <MODOUT>2</MODOUT>
            <MODSTAT>2</MODSTAT>
        </StudentOnModule>
        <StudentOnModule>
            <MODID>09|24899</MODID>
            <MODOUT>4</MODOUT>
            <MODSTAT>2</MODSTAT>
        </StudentOnModule>
    </Instance>
</Student>
<Student>
    <BIRTHDTE>1985-05-29</BIRTHDTE>
    <ULN>8402398897</ULN>
    <Instance>
        <NUMHUS>1</NUMHUS>
        <OWNINST>1439582|1</OWNINST>
        <FUNDCOMP>2</FUNDCOMP>
        <StudentOnModule>
            <MODID>09|12345</MODID>
            <MODOUT>4</MODOUT>
            <MODSTAT>2</MODSTAT>
        </StudentOnModule>
        <StudentOnModule>
            <MODID>09|24863</MODID>
            <MODOUT>2</MODOUT>
            <MODSTAT>2</MODSTAT>
        </StudentOnModule>
    </Instance>
    <Instance>
        <NUMHUS>2</NUMHUS>
        <OWNINST>1439582|2</OWNINST>
        <FUNDCOMP>2</FUNDCOMP>
        <StudentOnModule>
            <MODID>08|24685</MODID>
            <MODOUT>1</MODOUT>
            <MODSTAT>2</MODSTAT>
        </StudentOnModule>

    </Instance>
</Student>
```

My stylesheet for changing FUNDCOMP using OWNINST is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>        
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Student/Instance[OWNINST = document('ss6_FUNDCOMP.xml')/studentstoamend/STUDENT/OWNINST]/FUNDCOMP">
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('ss6_FUNDCOMP.xml')/studentstoamend/STUDENT[OWNINST = current()/../OWNINST]/FUNDCOMP"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And an example of an XML file containing new FUNDCOMP values is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<studentstoamend>
    <STUDENT>
        <OWNINST>1308538|1</OWNINST>
        <FUNDCOMP>2</FUNDCOMP>
    </STUDENT>
    <STUDENT>
        <OWNINST>1490044|1</OWNINST>
        <FUNDCOMP>1</FUNDCOMP>
    </STUDENT>
    <STUDENT>
        <OWNINST>1522978|2</OWNINST>
        <FUNDCOMP>1</FUNDCOMP>
    </STUDENT>
    <STUDENT>
        <OWNINST>903797|2</OWNINST>
        <FUNDCOMP>1</FUNDCOMP>
    </STUDENT>
    <STUDENT>
        <OWNINST>1231086|1</OWNINST>
        <FUNDCOMP>1</FUNDCOMP>
    </STUDENT>
</studentstoamend>
```

Comment: So do you want to add those values to the second file and then adjust the comparisons or do you want to hard-code the conditions or do you want to pass in a parameter with those `MODID`s?

Comment: Hi Martin.  What I want to do is change the value of MODOUT for a particular MODID, itself attached to a particular OWNINST.  The value I will change the MODOUT to will be set in the XML file that complements the XSL stylesheet.  So I guess the XML file will look something like the below (for each combination of OWNINST and MODID).  Does that make sense?  Thanks
    <STUDENT><OWNINST>1439582|1</OWNINST>
    <MODID>09|24864</MODID><MODOUT>6</MODOUT>
    </STUDENT>

Comment: The answer to this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952701/change-values-in-xml-based-to-those-referenced-in-another-xml-file-based-on-mult/46953868#46953868